# Using KeyDown, and using multiple keypresses

Tags: c#, keydown

I have been trying to make a simple test game(since I am new to C#), where you move a square around a form. While testing the game I was playing around I found that you could only move in one direction at a time. It has no errors, I would just like to be able to take in multiple keypresses at the same time.

My Code:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                y += 5;
                Invalidate();

            }
            
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                x += 5;
                Invalidate();
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
            {
                y -+= 5;
                Invalidate();

            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                x -= 5;
                Invalidate();
            }
```

Comment: What event are you using?

Comment: The `KeyDown` event ultimately comes from the similarly named Win32 `WM_KEYDOWN` message, and window messages are sequential by nature. You need to clarify what you actually expect to happen. From context, I believe your actual problem is that you're **holding down** two keys, and you observe that you get repeated keydown messages only for one of them. *That is just how it is*, if you program a game like this, you need to query keyboard input explicitly, rather relying on repeated keydown messages. Or set a flag in keydown, and clear that flag in keyup.

Comment: @Haytam KeyDown